# How to nest and combine a bunch of functions?

Tags: c++, templates, c++-templates

Like I have a bunch of functions, `f, g, h...`. How to easily combine them to `new_func(x) = f(g(h(x)))`? For convenience, we can assume that the last function has no parameters and that the other functions can be called nested.

Could the template parameter package achieve this?

update:

Actually, I want a way can give me a combination of functions, like

```
some_nest_method(f, g, h)(x) == f(g(h(x)))
```

Comment: Use a lambda?  `auto new_func = [](auto x) { return f(g(h(x))); };`

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry, I didn't make it clear. I was referring to the need for a general method (function or whatever) that could be used to achieve such a purpose. Not just the combination `f,g,h`.

Comment: You say "last function has no parameters": that doesn't match your example, regardless of which you call "last".  And how is a lambda not "easy"?  Please provide a more concrete problem; the lambda clearly lets you nest function calls and the syntax is terse and easy.  I can write function algebra systems, but with no specs or requirements, there is no point in spewing speculative code, especially when the lambda matches ALL of your listed requirements, yet is rejected due to reasons that are still unclear.

Comment: I mean, want to combine function bob and alice?  `[]{ return bob(alice()); }` is terse and does just that.  You might think this is being silly, but unless you have a reason why lambdas don't just do it, they really do just solve this problem in 99/100 cases.

Comment: @zclll I still fail to see how the lambda doesn't give you what you want?  What kind of syntax are you after?  `auto new_func = [](auto x) { return f(g(h(x))); };` is just as easy to write as `auto new_func = some_creator_function<paramter_type>(f, g, h);`

Comment: @NathanOliver I mean, I want a method that can create not just `f(g(h(x)))`, but also `a(b(c(x)))` an so on in the same way.

Comment: do you really need it to be c++11?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont updated my question to explain it clearly~

Comment: @zclll And you can.  When you want to use `a(b(c(x)))`, you just write `auto new_func_abc = [](auto x) { return a(b(c(x))); };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can merge the function recursively

something like this

```
template <typename F>
F combine(F f){return f;}

template <typename F, typename...Fs>
auto combine(F f, Fs ...fs){
    auto rest = combine(fs...);
    return [=](auto arg){
        return f(rest(arg));
    };
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/EzqjKr4q5

Comment: of course if possible I'd suggest the comment in your question is the way to go.

Comment: Suggestion: take `arg` as `auto&&` and use `std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg)` on it to forward.

Comment: @lorro yes it's a good suggestion, it can also take `auto&&...`, and forward/move all the functions, I leave them for showing the basic idea.

Comment: @apple_apple Yes, `auto&&...` is likely the best in this case.